# Finding set of upper bounds

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, upper-lower-bounds

In strict lexicographical ordering :Given the following

Find, if possible, three explicit upper bounds for $C = \{(x, y) \in  \mathbb{R}^2
| y < 0\}$. and write the set of upper bounds for $C$ in proper set notation. Does $C$ have a least upper bound? No proof is necessary, but do write a sentence or two explaining why or why not.

I had that the set of upper bounds would be $\{(x,y) \in  \mathbb{R}^2 | y \geq 0\} $ and three examples of upper bounds would be (-1,5),(3,4), and (-5,10). I found out my answer was incorrect, but I was confused as to why and where I went wrong - any hints or suggestions would be appreciated.

Also, I'm not sure if $C$ has a least upper bound or not, and I'm not sure how to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

In lexicographic ordering, $(x_1,y_1)<(x_2,y_2)$ if and only if either

- $x_1<x_2$ or
- $x_1=x_2$ and $y_1<y_2.$

Since the elements of $C$ range over all possible $x$-values, then it has ***no*** upper bounds. Indeed, if $(x^*,y^*)$ were an upper bound of $C$, then for all $x,y\in\Bbb R$ with $y<0,$ we would have $x<x^*$ or $x=x^*$ and $y<y^*.$ Consequently, $x\le x^*$ for all $x\in\Bbb R,$ so since $x^*\in\Bbb R,$ this would mean that $x^*$ is the greatest element of $\Bbb R.$

Comment: I understand, so since the set in $C$ is all the x-values, then it cannot have an upper bound because there is no greatest value of x? So then, in set notation, the set of all upper bounds would just be the empty set?

Comment: I would say rather that $C$ cannot have an upper bound because it's $x$-values don't. Note that $$B=\bigl\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x<1\bigr\}$$ has no greatest $x$-value, either, but any point $(u,v)$ with $u\ge 1$ will be an upper bound of $B$. As for $C,$ you're correct that its set of upper bounds is the empty set.